# how to filter an user input string and store the new filtered array

Tags: java, arrays, string, input, netbeans

I am taking a minor course on java programming and I am working on my assignment where I create a music box. An user will input a string which is the 'music notes' but it may contain other characters that has nothing to do with the music notes (aka So-Fa names, **DRMFSLT**). I have to filter the user input string and return a string containing proper music notes in UPPER CASE.

For example, user inputs '**D**i**r**p**M**$**F**q**s**w**L**2**t**' returns 'DRMFSLT'.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Song {

String notes;

public Song(String music) {
    notes = music;
    char[] store = new char[notes.length()-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); i++) {
        store[i] = notes.charAt(i);
    }

    char[][] valid = {{'D','R','M','F','S','L','T'},{'d','r','m','f','s','l','t'}};

    char[] clean = new char[store.length];

    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < valid.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < valid[0].length; k++) {
                if (store[i] == valid[j][k]) {
                    valid[0][k] = clean[a];
                    a++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    notes = String.valueOf(clean);
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(clean));
}
```

However, when I run it, no output is shown. It doesn't work at all and I have no idea why. Can someone kindly enlighten me and suggest a better way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that you never actually place anything in clean

Comment: edit your assign values for store because it is the size of the array and not the elements edit it to be `notes.length()` and not `notes.length()-1`

Comment: yea i know that it the size of the array, but the index of array starts from 0, so the size of the array should be length-1. Am I getting it wrong? Anyway I will change it to notes.length(), it does seem more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not actually needed to create a 2d array for valid if you want to convert it to uppercase letter look closer at your revised Song class I created

```
   public class Song 
{

    private String notes;

    public Song(String music) 
    {
        notes = music;
        char[] store = new char[notes.length()];
        int actualLetter=0;
        //loop for consuming the letters
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); ++i) 
        {
            if(Character.isLetter(notes.charAt(i)))
            {
                //converts a letter to uppercase
            store[i] = Character.toUpperCase(notes.charAt(i));

            }
        }
        //a valid array that is one dimensional
        char[] valid = {'D','R','M','F','S','L','T'};





            //looping for getting the actual size of clean
            for (int i = 0; i < store.length; ++i) 
            {
                for(int j=0;j<valid.length;++j)
                if (store[i] == valid[j]) 
                {
                    actualLetter++;
                }
            }
            char[] clean = new char[actualLetter];
            int a=0;
             //loop for getting equivalent letters
            for (int i = 0; i < store.length; ++i) 
            {
                for(int j=0;j<valid.length;++j)
                if (store[i] == valid[j]) 
                {
                    clean[a]=store[i];
                    a++;
                }
            }
            // output the values
        for(char clense:clean)
        {
            System.out.println(clense);
        }
    }
}
```

also in java char array is automatically filled with values '\u0000' if the array element is empty so empty values in store would be '\u0000'

Comment: ohhh that's a more organised way to code this! Thank you for the suggestion! But the problem of empty array elements still exists... I have looked for means to remove empty elements from the char array and people suggested converting the char array into a string and use **the replaceAll and trim functions** OR **ArrayUtils.removeElements**. Is this a good way to remove empty array elements?

Comment: where do empty array elements occur?

Comment: when `clean` is initialised with `actualLetter`, `actualLetter` equals to all the characters in `String notes`, which is not filtered and contains characters that do not belong to the So-Fa names. When So-Fa names are stored in `clean[a]`, there will be empty array elements.

Comment: @issy I have edited my answer for your convinience I add another loop for testing the actualLetter of So-Fa names if you think this answers your problem consider accepting it as an answer for other people future reference

Answer (score 0):

you are not storing anything in your output buffer. The shortest fix of your code might be in the inner most loops. (not considering all other improvements)

```
                if (store[i] == valid[j][k]) {
                    clean[a] = valid[0][k];
                    a++;
                }
```

Comment: so that's where everything went downhill. thank you so much for spotting the problem!

Comment: Thanks and welcom to so @jssy. If you find any answer helpful you can accept/upvote that.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply not storing valid notes in valid. Instead:

```
 valid[0][k] = clean[a];
```

Write:

```
clean[a] = valid[0][k];
```

Comment: so that's why it doesn't work! Thank you for spotting the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You never actually placed anything inside the array clean. You defined its length and initialized it, but it is just empty space. Try modifying the code and including 
**clean[x] = //other char ;**

Comment: Thank you for spotting the problem. Didn't realise that stupid mistake:(

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Song {

    String notes;

    public Song(String music) {

        notes = music;
        char[] store = new char[notes.length()];

        //Here you could have a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because the size of the arrays isn't the same
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.length(); i++) {
            store[i] = notes.charAt(i);
        }

        char[][] valid = { { 'D', 'R', 'M', 'F', 'S', 'L', 'T' }, { 'd', 'r', 'm', 'f', 's', 'l', 't' } };

        char[] clean = new char[store.length];

        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < valid.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < valid[0].length; k++) {
                    if (store[i] == valid[j][k]) {
                        //This assignation was wrong, you were assignating it to 'valid' array but it must be on clean which will contain the clean notes 
                        clean[a] = valid[0][k];
                        a++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        notes = String.valueOf(clean);
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(clean));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Song song = new Song("DirpM$FqswL2t");
    }
}
```

Output:
DRMFSLT

Note: I created a main method to run your program.

Comment: The main method is coded in another class so it's not here haha. OMG thank you for spotting the assignation problem. I didn't realise I made that stupid mistake.